# Origin of "Toll jemandem sein"

Tags: etymology, history

What is the origin of "Toll jemande* sein". For example "wenn du toll mir bist" in this song.

https://youtu.be/CK5MdsewTjM

(Can someone please help me embed it? (Lol, what's that supposed to mean in this context?))

Can perhaps its usage be traced back to earlier languages?

Comment: Es heisst eindeutig _"wenn Du treu mir bist"_. Deine Frage ist Quatsch, Du hast Dich verhört.

Answer (score 6):

It's

> wenn du treu mir bist
>   (faithful).

There is nothing like

> Toll jemandem sein

Neither in the song nor in German in general.